# Unable to delete Firebase Storage Image with Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Changed Storage path from "yourmaps" to "users" for this question
[image]Attempting to delete an image from Firebase Storage.
I have read similar stack overflow questions and attempted to solve this for days without effort.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
admin.initializeApp();
```

A user uuid is passed to the cloud function when a users account has been deleted. i am attempting to delete the user image which has the same uuid in firebase Storage.

```
exports.storageImageDelete = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {

      const userId = context.params.userId
      const path = `users/${userId}.jpg`;
      const bucketName = 'xxxxxxx.appspot.com/'
      const storage = new Storage();

      return storage.bucket(bucketName).file(path).delete()
        .then(function () {
          console.log(`File deleted successfully in path: ${path}`)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(path).delete())
          console.info(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(path).delete())
          console.log(`File NOT deleted: ${path}`)
        })
      });
```

Error message in Firebase Storage Log. Path is correct however there is no object...

```
Error: No such object: xxxxxx.appspot.com/users/XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX.jpg
```

In Firebase Storage "Monitor rules" i can see that my attempts are allowed. Any help would be appreciated. What am i missing?

Comment: Is `xxxxxxx.appspot.com` your default Storage bucket?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Hi & yes, it is my Default bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. I needed to state the storageBucket when initialising app. Now i can correctly find my bucket.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx.appspot.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your default bucket, the following should do the trick (untested):

#### Version with `then` (not using async/await)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.storageImageDelete = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{userId}')
    .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

      const userId = context.params.userId
      const path = `users/${userId}.jpg`;

      const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
      
      return bucket.file(path).delete()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`File deleted successfully in path: ${path}`)
          return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(`File NOT deleted: ${path}`);
          return null;
        })
      });
```

#### Version using `async`/`await`

```
exports.storageImageDelete = functions.firestore
.document('user/{userId}')
.onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
    
    try {
        const userId = context.params.userId
        const path = `users/${userId}.jpg`;
      
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        
        await bucket.file(path).delete();
        
        console.log(`File deleted successfully in path: ${path}`)
        return null;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`File NOT deleted: ${path}`);
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
    
  });
```

In other words, no need to declare the bucket as you do, you can directly declare it with `admin.storage().bucket()`.

Comment: Tried Version using async/await and i still get the same error "No such object". pathway to image in the Cloud function and in firebase Storage are identical. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Redstain Can you pls add a screenshot of your bucket, which shows the file you want to delete.

Comment: Added screenshot from bucket. I changed the pathway to the Storage from "yourmaps" to "users" for this question. Am i doing something incorrectly somehow?

Comment: @Redstain I've just tried the code and I confirm it does work on my side. Are you 100% sure the file path is correct? Did you remove the `const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');` line (normally keeping it should not trigger any error but just to try everything...)?

Comment: Path to image yourmaps/3E2A9388-603A-4378-AA86-990E72675876.jpg. I did remove code "const {Storage} = require.... Only thing i can think of is that it is a problem with permissions or that it fails since i have two cloud functions being triggered at the same time.

Comment: "problem with permissions" => Normally the Admin SDK has full rights on the Firebase services.

Comment: Then i am soon out of ideas. Code i use when uploading to Firebase Storage from swift `let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("yourmaps/\(uuid).jpg")`

Comment: Please try to improve your post by letting us know what posts and answers have you tried and didn't work for you. Make sure your path is correct. Not sure what post you have tried but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011991/getting-error-no-such-object-when-deleting-file-on-firebase-storage-using-cloud) is a similar one.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópezAcuña I have seen that post and i do not have that problem unfortunately. The file i am attempting to delete is in the default bucket and within a folder called "yourmaps"  which creates the path `xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/yourmaps/3E2A9388-603A-4378-AA86-990E72675876.jpg` Maybe i need to create a Serviceaccount for this to work.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópezAcuña  I managed to solve the issue which i have now posted as an answer. The problem seems to be that you need to state the storageBucket when initialising app.